# "ReferenceError: compression is not defined" when deploying Node.js app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Why is Heroku saying compression is undefined?? If I manually set process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production' and run the app with node server everything works fine....

error log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0669f4c9f937a0e47034

project code: https://github.com/leptone/user-info

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means you need to install the compression library in your `package.json` -- since it isn't currently listed in there, Heroku hasn't installed the library, and that's why your code is failing =)

You should be able to run

```
npm install --save compression
```

Then commit the changes to your `package.json`, and you should be good to go!

Comment: The error means that library is NOT available. The only other thing it could mean is that your push to Heroku failed before receiving that commit, and therefore the package was not installed. If you run `git push heroku master` do you see it being installed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had hard coded my port number to 3000. I needed to use

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

I don't know why it was tripping up at

```
app.use(compression())
```

but correcting the port fixed the problem.